# Failed PyCharm GitHub push because of large file size. How can I remove offending folder from version control and re-initiate the push?

Tags: git

Tried to implement version control for a Python project on PyCharm. During initial commit, one folder (that I didn't need to have under version control in the first place) caused an error because of large file size.

Now I don't know how to remove that folder from version control, and how push the initial commit again (minus this folder).

PyCharm doesn't see any changes in the files already committed and so won't push them, and even when I add the large folder to .gitignore it still doesn't show up highlighted red.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history